# change constraint inside tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, uitableview

I need to change a width constraint of a `UIView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. Usually I would create an `IBOutlet` to the constraint but how do I go about that as it's a dynamic prototypes tableView ? Please suggest

Thanks!

Comment: By dynamic table view I'm guessing you mean it's created in code? Have you setup your auto layout in code or did you just set the old frame property?

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I meant dynamic tableView as in not static. I'm using cellForRowAtIndexPath: to setup cells and not designing them in interface builder. The tableView itself is added in IB with constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following way

1. Either by creating new view dynamically

   `UIView *v=[[UIView alloc]init];
    v.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 250);`
2. Or by accessing view by tag or by accessing content view subviews in `-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

   `UIView *v=[cell.contentView.subviews  objectAtIndex:0];
    v.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 250);`

Hope this helps

Comment: I thought of using viewWithTag but I can't set a tag to the constraint. Also, is it a good idea to use CGRectMake when I'm using AutoLayout? Even thought it's in a tableViewCell?

Comment: I thought you would be using the Autoresizing but yes you can use the as `[v addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pageView
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                      toItem:nil
                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                    constant:200.0]];`

Comment: I'll use that! Thanks ;)